# How to output jsp var to html

Tags: bash, jsp, shell

I would have thought this straight forward, but it doesn't seem the case.

Aim: I am running a shell script `ArgCHeck.sh` through my .jsp file. This works fine and I can see the output in my system console.

However when I try and output the line into the browser through HTML, its doesn't seem to work.

I have tried setting the String to `Static final String line = "test";` and this works to output the word test, but not the value I want which is from the other String line.

Its probably something I missed, but any help is appreciate.

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%!

%>
<%
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=null;
String s=null;
String cmd="/tools/scripts/ArgCheck.sh orange";

p=r.exec(cmd);
InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
System.out.println(line);
}
p.waitFor();


System.out.println(p.exitValue());
%>
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <%
    // This scriptlet generates HTML output
    out.println( String.valueOf( line ));
%>
    </body>
</html>
```

--------------------------- Edit -----------------------------------------------------

That's what you get when you cut and paste. I read the code and it was obvious. Time for a break.

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>

<html>
<head>
<head/>

<body>


<% 
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=null;
String s=null;
String cmd="/tools/scripts/ArgCheck.sh";

p=r.exec(cmd);
InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
out.println(line);
}
p.waitFor();
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.. Just Change the file path .

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%!
private String runScriptFile(){
    String strRetVal = "";
    Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p=null;
    String s=null;
    String cmd="D:\\test.bat";
    try{
        p=r.exec(cmd);
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            strRetVal += line + "<br>";
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        p.waitFor();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strRetVal;
}
%>
<%
String line = runScriptFile();
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Batch File Test</title>
    <head/>
    <body>
<%
    // This scriptlet generates HTML output
    out.println( String.valueOf( line ));
%>
    </body>
</html>
```